# Square Brackets With Superscript on Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

From pp.20 in the book "[A Fenics Tutorial](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/83776282/fenics-book-2011-10-27-final.pdf)" by Logg we see the following passage:

[image]

My question is:  What does the [V]<sup>d</sup> mean?  What do square brackets around a vector space mean?  Is there a reference for this?

Comment: Sounds to me as if: If $V$ is the space of (continuous, differentiable, smooth, ...) functions $\Omega\to \Bbb R$, then $[V]^d$ shall denote  the space of (continuous, differentiable, smooth, ...) functions $\Omega\to \Bbb R^d$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a function space of functions $u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. For example $V=C(\Omega)$, $L^2(\Omega)$, $H^1(\Omega)$. Note that one can also write $L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$ to explicitly indicate that the functions map to $\mathbb{R}$.

Then there are lot of different notations in literature to indicate the spaces $C(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d)$, $L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d)$, $H^1(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d)$, which are spaces of vector-valued functions $u:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^d$.

One sees for example $L^2(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^d), L^2(\Omega)^d, \{L^2(\Omega)\}^d, \mathbf{L}(\Omega), \mathbb{L}(\Omega), [L(\Omega)]^d$. You asked about the last one. Here are some references where they use exactly that notation:

- Arndt, Daniel, Helene Dallmann, and Gert Lube. "Local projection FEM stabilization for the time‐dependent incompressible Navier–Stokes problem." Numerical Methods for Partial Differential Equations 31.4 (2015): 1224-1250.
- Du, Qiang, and Max D. Gunzburger. "Analysis of a Ladyzhenskaya model for incompressible viscous flow." Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 155.1 (1991): 21-45.
- Feireisl, Eduard, Antonın Novotný, and Hana Petzeltová. "On the existence of globally defined weak solutions to the Navier—Stokes equations." Journal of Mathematical Fluid Mechanics 3.4 (2001): 358-392.